# Tomcat and maximum number of requested accepted

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat5.5

Is there a way to configure Tomcat to reject a request after a specific threshold number? E.g. after 506 requests start rejecting.
Is there such an option or am I supposed to write code for this?

Comment: 506 _concurrent_ requests, or just 506 requests in total? 506 requests on _any_ URL provided by the app server, or just on one particular URL ?

Comment: @DaveHowes:Good point!506 concurrent requests on a particular URL.Is there a significant difference on any URL?

Comment: Wasn't sure if you wanted to just say "After I've had 506 requests on index.jsp then I'm not going to allow any more", which would be easy enough to implement but you'd have to code for, or "After the server has had 506 requests on any URL then I'm not going to allow any more", which would be a bit harder. If it's concurrent requests then have a look here : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html - I think the "acceptCount" parameter is what you are after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat's connectors can be configured to only service a certain number of requests simultaneously -- that's configured as the `maxConnections` attribute of a `<Connector>` in `server.xml`. (You can also configure the `acceptCount` but that's actually a queue of connections that the OS maintains that pile-up after `maxConnections` has been reached). This limits simultaneous connections to Tomcat *across all URLs* -- that is, it's just total connections that are being limited.

If you want to limit the number of simultaneous connections to a *specific URL* (or specific set of URLs for that matter), you may have to write your own code. I've heard that [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) has a lot of QOS (quality-of-service) features like this that you might be able to use without writing your own code.

Otherwise, you'll be forced to write your own code -- probably a `Filter` that simply keeps track of how many requests are in-progress and then rejecting those that come in after some limit has been reached. Beware of synchronization issues with counters being used across threads.